# Cypress/JavaScript: Parameter on request path (response.body.VARIABLE)

Tags: javascript, cypress, mocha.js, response, chai

Was trying to figure out how to pass a variable on a response path like this

```
response.response.body.data.groupsData.hereGoesTheVariable
```

Where the **variable is one of the attributes** like name, id, etc. This way I can create a function and just pass the desire attribute.

I was trying template literals and so but with no affect. Any idea?

I'm getting the response from

```
 cy.wait('@' + alias).then(response => {
const text = response.response.body.data.groups.attribute; });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Properties can be accessed using dot notation like:

```js
response.response.body.data.groupsData
```

or by bracket notation like

```js
response.response.body.data["groupsData"]
```

where the thing in the brackets is a string, *or a variable*.

So, if `hereGoesTheVariable` is your variable,

```js
const hereGoesTheVariable = 'somePropertyName';
const text = response.response.body.data.groupsData[hereGoesTheVariable]
```

this is equivalent to

```js
const text = response.response.body.data.groupsData.somePropertyName
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm.
By the way, do you also know if there a way of sending different attribute in the same variable? Like let's say
Variable = name.id

Comment: Yes, should be ok with `response.response.body.data.groupsData[name.id]` for example.